# use mongoose model.find() to get all entries of only 1 field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, iframe, mongoose

I've tried to use different variation of model.find(), but none do what I want.

code below is what I'm working with, but it displays every single field, and I only want the "iframe" field.

```
app.get('/api/videos', function (req, res) {
    Video.find({}, function (err, docs) {
       res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

Code below does work and I only get the 'iframe' field, but it reverses the json output and I don't want that. It also get unique values, even though it's not that important since every entry is unique.

```
app.get('/api/videos', function (req, res) {
    Video.find().distinct('iframe', function (err, docs) {
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

W

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection):

```
Video.find({}, {iframe: 1}, function (err, docs) {
   res.json(docs);
});
```

The second parameter to the `find` function tells which field to return. If you do not want the `_id` as well, then use: `{_id:0, iframe:1}`

Like so:

```
Video.find({}, {_id:0, iframe:1}, function (err, docs) {
   res.json(docs);
});
```

---

However, projection does not give you *distinct* values. It only returns the fields you want to use (along with repetitions).

Comment: Ah that's how the second parameter works, didn't understand earlier when I read upon it. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: No probs. Updated my answer to say that `projection` doesn't give you distinct values, just so you know.